# Get Data from One Table and Insert to Another Via Form Submission

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

How do I get a UserID from one database table (Users) to be **inserted** into another table (Ticket)?  Both columns in each table has the same datatype (int).  Please take a look:

**Users**
UserID
UserName
Password
FirstName
LastName
Email
Updated
Deleted

**Ticket**
TicketID
DateCreated
`UserIDNum` FK
FullName
Email
Subject
Message
Deleted

These are all of the codes involved:

```
    Partial Public Class mysupport
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = True
        SetFocus(helpTopicDDL)
    Else
        SetFocus(fullNameTXTBOX)
    End If


    Dim sConnection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TrackTicketsConnectionString2").ConnectionString)
    sConnection.Open()

    If Session("Ticket") Is Nothing Then
        Response.Redirect("SignIn.aspx")
    Else
        Dim cmdS As String = "Select * from Users Where Deleted='N' AND Username=@Username"
        Dim cmdCheckEmail As New SqlCommand(cmdS, sConnection)

        Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Username", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
        cmdCheckEmail.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        cmdCheckEmail.Parameters.Item("@Username").Value = Session("Ticket")

        Dim obj As Object = cmdCheckEmail.ExecuteScalar()

        If obj IsNot Nothing Then
            mailLBL.Text = Convert.ToString(obj)
        End If
    End If

    sConnection.Close()
End Sub

Protected Sub submitBTN_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles submitBTN.Click

    Dim sdConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("TrackTicketsConnectionString2")
    Dim iRowCount As Integer
    Dim cmdInsertTicket As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim conticket As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    conticket.ConnectionString = sdConnection

    cmdInsertTicket.Connection = conticket
    cmdInsertTicket.CommandText = "Insert Into Ticket " _
    & "( DateCreated, FullName, Email, TicketType, Subject, Message, Deleted)" _
    & "Values( @DateCreated, @FullName, @Email, @TicketType, @Subject, @Message, @Deleted)"

    'Dim appUserName As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@UserName", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    'cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Add(appUserName)
    'cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Item("@UserName").Value = User.Identity.Name

    Dim appDateCreated As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@DateCreated", Data.SqlDbType.DateTime)
    cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Add(appDateCreated)
    cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Item("@DateCreated").Value = Now()

    Dim appFullName As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@FullName", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Add(appFullName)
    cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Item("@FullName").Value = fullNameTXTBOX.Text

    Dim appEmail As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Email", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Add(appEmail)
    cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Item("@Email").Value = emailAddTXTBOX.Text

    Dim appTicketType As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@TicketType", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Add(appTicketType)
    cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Item("@TicketType").Value = helpTopicDDL.SelectedValue

    Dim appSubject As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Subject", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Add(appSubject)
    cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Item("@Subject").Value = subjectTXTBOX.Text

    Dim appMessage As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Message", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Add(appMessage)
    cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Item("@Message").Value = messageTXTBOX.Text

    Dim appDeleted As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Deleted", Data.SqlDbType.Char)
    cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Add(appDeleted)
    cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Item("@Deleted").Value = "N"

    conticket.Open()
    Try
        iRowCount = cmdInsertTicket.ExecuteScalar()
        statusLBL.Text = "Ticket has been submitted successfully."

    Catch
        statusLBL.Text = "Ticket has not been submitted.  Please try again."

    End Try

    conticket.Close()

End Sub
```

What I really wanted is for a person's UserID to be stored in **Ticket** table after he has logged in to fill out a form and submitted it.  I'm at a loss in how to pull the data from Users table to insert into Ticket table.  Any help is much appreciated as I'm still learning.

Comment: How are you authenticating the user? FormsAuthentication?

Comment: @SeanPetiya: Yes. I'm using Form Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Inserting the `UserID` into the `Tickets` table when adding a record first requires that you have access to the `UserID` value. You then need to pass this value in your `INSERT` statement.

Looks like we first need to retrieve the UserId. Since you are using `FormsAuthentication` we can retrieve the UserName from the `User.Identity.Name` object and use that as the value in our first query to retrieve the UserId.

```
    Dim cmdS As String = "Select [UserID] from Users Where Deleted='N' AND UserName=@UserName"
    Dim cmdGetUserId As New SqlCommand(cmdS, sConnection)

    Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@UserName", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmdGetUserId.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmdGetUserId.Parameters.Item("@UserName").Value = User.Identity.Name

    Dim obj As Object = cmdGetUserId.ExecuteScalar
    Dim myUserId As Integer = Integer.Parse(obj)
```

Now that we have the UserId value for our current user we can modify our `INSERT` statement and parameters.

```
   cmdInsertTicket.Connection = conticket
   cmdInsertTicket.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Ticket " _
   & "(UserID, DateCreated, FullName, Email, TicketType, Subject, Message, Deleted)" _
   & "Values(@UserID, @DateCreated, @FullName, @Email, @TicketType, @Subject, @Message, @Deleted)"

   Dim appUserId As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@UserID", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
   cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Add(appUserId)
   cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Item("@UserID").Value = myUserId

   Dim appDateCreated As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@DateCreated", Data.SqlDbType.DateTime)
   cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Add(appDateCreated)
   cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Item("@DateCreated").Value = Now()

   ...

   Dim appDeleted As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Deleted", Data.SqlDbType.Char)
   cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Add(appDeleted)
   cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Item("@Deleted").Value = "N"
```

You can access authentication information through the `User.Identity` object once the user has been authenticated. Might also want to think about implementing a custom  `IIdentity` class to store the UserID if you will need access to it often. Here's a good MSDN article about Custom Authentication: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172766(v=vs.80).aspx

UPDATE:

In regards to the comment below, you are retrieving the **UserID** because the `SqlCommand` is being executed with the `ExecuteScalar` method which returns the value of the first column of the first row. I would recommend taking a closer look at the `SqlCommand` object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx and this ADO.NET primer on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Can I do this: `cmdInsertTicket.Parameters.Item("@UserIDNum").Value = User.Identity.Name` and then query the Users table for the record?  Also, thanks for the MSDN article!

Comment: Could you include all of the code for this query? I'm assuming `@UserIDNum` is an integer and `User.Identity.Name` is going to be a string, but I'd like to see how you are querying the database so I can give you a better answer.

Comment: You're right, `@UserIDNum` is an integer.  I haven't figured out the query yet but I'm going to work on it.

Comment: I've just added all my codes here.  Previously, under Person's Info (mailLBL), it will display the **user's email** and now it displays the **UserID**.  Please advise what I did wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: @FabianBigler: Can you kindly help me?